# AngularJS Jasmine comparing arrays returning error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to test the value of myArray after pushing data to it but I am always getting error that the array content is not equal to my static arr var. Can someone please check my code below and let me know what exactly I am doing wrong here and why the 2 arrays are reported by Jasmine as not equal? Thanks

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

  var MainCtrl, scope;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('Final ordered array of equation elements', function () {
      var arr = ["1", "2", "3", ".test[]"];
      expect(scope.myArray).toBe(arr);    
  });    


});



angular.controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.myArray = [];
    $scope.myStr = '123.test[]';

    $scope.myArray.push($scope.myStr.slice(0,1), 
                            $scope.myStr.slice(1,2),
                            $scope.myStr.slice(2,3),
                            $scope.myStr.slice(3));
    console.log(myArray); //returns ["1", "2", "3", ".test[]"]

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toBe() compares with === which means they need to be identical objects not just identical values. Have you tried `expect(scope.myArray).toEqual(arr);`